# my code is always returning ALL products for the specified category ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Based on a category ID, I am trying to retrieve the relevant products under that category. However, all category ID I tried seems to return ALL products I have in the database and not those who belong to the category ID, here is my relevant code:

```
$args = array(
           'post_type' => 'product',
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'category' => 24
         );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.the_title().'</a>';

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Even if I ommit the category argument, the code still returning All products. How to fix that so I get only the relevant products for the specified category ID?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Anand comments, I figured out the way to do so:

```
$term = get_term($_GET['catId'],'product_cat');// first parameter is the cat ID

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,// unlimited posts
               'product_cat' => $term->name,// Pass the category name
        );
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Comment: It wasn't about the upvote, was trying to see where I was failing to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$term = get_term( 24, 'product_cat' );

$args = array(
           'post_type' => 'product',
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
           'product_cat' => $term->name
         );
```

Comment: my apologies, didn't realize it was Woocommerce products, you need to use `product_cat` and the name of the category. Code updated above.

Comment: Thanks, but i am dealing with category ID not category name :)

Comment: Category is custom taxonomy (product_cat) . The categories you create will have a tag_id. When you navigate to Products -> Categories, the URL will be like `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, changed `product_cat` to `tag_ID` and specifying the category ID doesn't change the behavior, I got always the same products for all categories ID

Comment: Use `get_term(24,'product_cat')` and then pass the name of the term using `$term->name` to the $args array.